# having trouble creating Bundles

Tags: symfony

After Installing symphony on Ubuntu when i am try to execute this line code it gives me Error.

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml
```

When Executing this code the error of the code is

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/kashif/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/kashif/Symfony/app/console on line 10
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/kashif/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/kashif/Symfony/app/console on line 10
```

Comment: Obviously the file is missing. Redownload the .zip and try again.

Comment: bootstrap.php.cache is generated during the installation. run composer install.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Jakub Zalas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330267/jakub-zalas) says, you must run the `composer install` in order to generate the `app/bootstrap.php.cache` file.

If you look at the content of `composer.json` you'll see this line `Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap` into `post-install-cmd` block.

This line generate the missing file.

Hope it's helpful.

Best regard

Answer (score 0):

`composer update -o` or `composer install -o` should do the trick.

Another workaroung if you're still developing and using a debugger like xdebug would be commenting out ...

```
// $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
```

... and ...

```
// $kernel->loadClassCache();
```

plus adding the line ...

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
```

... before ...

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
```

... in `web/app_dev.php` as described in the documentation chapter [How to optimize your development Environment for debugging](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/debugging.html).